# Calculate the new control points for cubic Bezier curve in Android Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, curve, bezier, cubic

In the application I am developing currently, I am having a challenge drawing a bezire curve between start and end points to join 2 lines as shown in the image below.
[image: red curve is the bezire curve I need to achieve]

The distance between the lines are 10dp as marked in the image. I needed a solid method to achive the curves as shown in the imaage attached with the following inputs - start coordinates, end coordinates, distance of the curve, gap between 2 lines [ 10dp - as shown in picture]. Can any one suggest a solid method to achieve my desired results?

I tried using path.cubicto() function with start coordinates(X1,Y1) and with trail and error method, I identified some range of constants values(which varies with the curve length) when added/Substracted with original start and end points(X1 + Xoffset,Y1 - Yoffset) to obtain 1st control point, and similarly (X3 - Xoffset, Y3+ Yoffset) to obtain the second control point. By having the start [ X1,Y1] and end [X3,Y3] coordinates for any line as constants already, I could always get the distance of the curve by substracting the Ystart from Yend. I tried linearly interpolating the distance values to the range of Offset constants but the curve starts losing its shape where I was expecting it to be in proper shape.

Comment: The problem here is that there is no such thing as a "straight line" on a cubic curve, so you need two: one for the upper bend, and one for the lower bend, with a straight line connecting them if they're bridging more than one step.

Comment: Agreed, but with careful selection of the control points, a curved Z shape with a straight line in between could be achieved [ I did that on a POC with trail and error based control points]  May be the approach should be divided into 3 things as you said, top curve, straight line, bottom curve - but I am curious if any one can suggest a control point calculation method here to retain this shape on a cubic Bezier?

Comment: You literally can't, that's a defining property of cubic curve. So save yourself the headache and just use two of them, with a connecting vertical as needed, and things become _so_ much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is no such thing as a "straight line" on a cubic curve, so you need two: one for the upper bend, and one for the lower bend, with a straight line connecting them if they're bridging more than one step.

Getting the coordinates for given your picture, with terminal `x` positions `t1` and `t2`, on row `r1`, `r2`, `r...`, and vertical spacing `10px`, these curves are trivial:

[image]

(where `cx` is `(t1 + t2) / 2` and `cy` is `(r1+r2) / 2`)

You simply make every connection "two curves and a straight line if necessary": each cubic (and they *need* to be cubic if you want them to look straight enough at both the horizontal and vertical connection) has a start coordinate at the terminal, a first control point at the horizontal midway point between two terminals, a second control point at exactly the same point, and then an end coordinate at that same `x` coordinate, but half the distance between rows down.

The first curve is:

```
S = (t1, r1)
c1 = (cx, r1)
c2 = (cx, r1)
E = (cx, cy)
```

And the second curve is:

```
S = (cx, cy)
c1 = (cx, r2)
c2 = (cx, r2)
E = (t2, r2)
```

And then we simply add a straight line running from `r1 + 5px` to `r... - 5px` if the vertical distance is more than one row.

And if you want a slightly weaker radius, you move all those control points closer to their respective on-curve points (so the first control point towards the start, the second control points towards the end).